# MSChart - Multiple columns grouped by date

Tags: mschart

I need to display % utilization for several production lines over several days. So my Y axis will be the % values. I need bars for each of the production lines on each of the days. So my X axis would be groups of columns each labeled for the production line and then grouped and labeled for the date. How would I do this with the MSchart.

Below is a sample of what I need. It shows only 2 production lines (I will need to display more than 2 production lines) and does not include the production line name in the X-axis label.

[image]

I am almost there. Here is an image of the chart I am creating:

[image]

And here is the code that created it:

```
Private Sub ChartSetup()
    Try
        dvCapacityUtilization.RowFilter = ""
        dvCapacityUtilization.Sort = "Period ASC, CutUpSet ASC"
        Me.cuChart.BeginInit()
        With Me.cuChart
            .ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval = 30
            .ChartAreas(0).AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "MM/yy"
            .ChartAreas(0).AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = -90
            .ChartAreas(0).AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Gray
            .ChartAreas(0).AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.White
            .ChartAreas(0).AxisX.MinorGrid.LineColor = Color.White
            .DataBindCrossTable(dvCapacityUtilization, _
                "CutUpSet", "Period", "CapacityUtilization", "Label = CapacityUtilization")
        End With
        '
        For Each series In Me.cuChart.Series
            series.IsValueShownAsLabel = False
            series.LabelFormat = "0.0%"
            series.SetCustomProperty("PointWidth", "0.5")
            series.SetCustomProperty("DrawingStyle", "Cylinder")
            series.XValueType = DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.Date
        Next
        Me.cuChart.EndInit()
    Catch ex As Exception
        ErrHandler(Me.Name & " - Chart Setup", ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

1. How do I turn the value labels off? In my code I used IsValueShownAsLabel = False but they are still displayed. I eventually will allow the user to turn the values on or off.
2. How do I format the values as XX.X%. In my code I used LabelFormat = 0.0% but that did not work.
3. How can I get the X axis labels to be the dates associated with the data values. In my code I used AxisX.Interval = 30 just to get the labels on the chart.

Follow up:
As stated in #1 above, I used series.IsValueShownAsLabel = False but the value labels were still displayed. To remove them I had to do the following:

For Each point in series.Points
   point.Label = String.Empty
Next

Why should I have to do this instead of using IsValueShownAsLabel = False?

Answer (score 1):

WINFORM : Finally find out with some R&D. Please follow below steps.

**1. Drag and Drop new chart control from ToolBox in new winform.**

**2. Remove default "Series1" as it's dynamically generated as per column values.**

**3. Assume that we have following sample datatable.**

```
 public DataTable GetDataTable()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("UtilizationDate", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("ProductionLine", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("UtilizationValue", typeof(int));

            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = DateTime.Now;
            dr[1] = "Proy01";
            dr[2] = 25;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);          

            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = DateTime.Now;
            dr[1] = "Proy02";
            dr[2] = 15;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);


            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = DateTime.Now;
            dr[1] = "Proy03";
            dr[2] = 125;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);



            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
            dr[1] = "Proy01";
            dr[2] = 13;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
            dr[1] = "Proy02";
            dr[2] = 111;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);


            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
            dr[1] = "Proy03";
            dr[2] = 77;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);


            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2);
            dr[1] = "Proy01";
            dr[2] = 13;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2);
            dr[1] = "Proy02";
            dr[2] = 111;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);


            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2);
            dr[1] = "Proy03";
            dr[2] = 77;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            return dt;
        }
```

**4.  Now add following line of code using DataBindCrossTable.**

```
chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Months;
            chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "MM-yy";
            DataTable dt = GetDataTable();
            chart1.DataBindCrossTable(dt.DefaultView, "ProductionLine", "UtilizationDate", "UtilizationValue", "Label=UtilizationValue");



            foreach (Series item in chart1.Series)
            {              
                item.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
                item["PixelPointWidth"] = "50";
                item["DrawingStyle"] = "Cylinder";
                item.XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am working in WinForms but get the gist of your code. I need to have multiple columns per date. I believe yours only has one column. I would also like to label each column as well as the date. How can I do that?

Comment: could you please post sample chart image you want ?

Comment: I have added a sample image. This would be for 2 production lines. I may have up to 10 production lines. I would also like to include the line name in the X-axis notation if possible. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you for all your help, mit. I sincerely appreciate it. I have added an image of the chart I am creating and the code with 3 questions. I am nearly there. Thanks again.